# MySQL RAND() seed values almost repeat

Tags: mysql, random, random-seed

Using MySQL 5.6.21 on Windows 7.

I am attempting to return a 'random' row from a table seeded by the date (so the same row returns for the current day and then switches the next day etc - a "random quote of the day generator" if you like).

I noticed the same rows keep coming up so I simplified the query to its basics, it appears the RAND() function generates *very* similar numbers every fourth seed value. When rounded to an integer the values appear to repeat every fourth seed. This example only uses 16 rows, but you get the idea.

```
create table t (i INT);

insert into t values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15);

select i, ceil(rand(i) * 16), rand(i) from t;

drop table t;
```

Gives...

```
0   3   0.15522042769493574
1   7   0.40540353712197724
2   11  0.6555866465490187
3   15  0.9057697559760601
4   3   0.15595286540310166
5   7   0.40613597483014313
6   11  0.6563190842571847
7   15  0.9065021936842261
8   3   0.15668530311126755
9   7   0.406868412538309
10  11  0.6570515219653505
11  15  0.907234631392392
12  3   0.15741774081943347
13  7   0.40760085024647497
14  11  0.6577839596735164
15  15  0.9079670691005579
```

Not what I expected, so what am I doing wrong? I expected a pseudo-random sequence to be generated.

Comment: Oh my, that's a *very* dodgy RNG function they have.

Comment: That's what I thought. I have reverted to doing the random number seeding and generation in PHP. It means doing two queries but it works consistently.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation RAND(n) is working properly only if n is constant. **The effect of using a nonconstant argument is undefined. As of MySQL 5.0.13, nonconstant arguments are not permitted.**

And as they say **RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version.**

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Check what will happen if you use RAND() without parameter.

Comment: Well, I have to seed RAND() if I want the same value returned for multiple queries. You can also reproduce the behaviour with statically defined seeds...

select rand(0),rand(1),rand(2),rand(3),rand(4),rand(5),rand(6),rand(7),rand(8);

select ceil(rand(0)*16),ceil(rand(1)*16),ceil(rand(2)*16),ceil(rand(3)*16),ceil(rand(4)*16),ceil(rand(5)*16),ceil(rand(6)*16),ceil(rand(7)*16),ceil(rand(8)*16);

Comment: To answer your other point, yes, if you seed rand() then use it multiple times, it generates a pseudo-random sequence from the first value. My point is that the first rand() value returned is *very* sensitive to the seed. Repeating to the third decimal place every 4th increment of the seed.

Comment: I think this does answer the question; as RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator.

Answer (score 0):

RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator, so if it is not suitable, then other ways of generating random numbers should be used. In my case, I needed to order rows differently per day, and `RAND(CURDATE()+0)` proved to be a viable solution.

Yes, it does seem as though the first term has a cycle of 4, and it will be given a similar random number each time the seed increments by 4.

I got the following results from my own basic testing of random number generation and incrementing the seed by 4 each time, using the seed number 0, 4, 8, and 12.

- Row 1: Incremented by about 0.001
- Row 2: Incremented by about 0.005
- Row 3: Incremented by about 0.02
- Row 4: Incremented by about 0.05
- Row 5: Incremented by about 0.2
- Row 6: Decremented by about 0.01 (or maybe it incremented by 0.99)
- Row 7: Incremented by about 0.26

In OP's example, because they don't use a constant seed number, they technically have a sample size of 1. The impact with recurring indexes is lessened as the row count increases, and there is a higher chance that other items will appear before or after other items when they wouldn't have previously.

A couple of caveats I've worked out from using `RAND()`:

If `RAND()` is only used as a `SELECT` column or `WHERE` condition, and a `LIMIT` is specified, then `RAND()` will only be generated once for each of the returned rows.

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15);
SELECT i, RAND(0) FROM t LIMIT 0, 1; # 0, 0.15522042769493574
SELECT i, RAND(0) FROM t LIMIT 1, 1; # 1, 0.15522042769493574
```

If `RAND()` is used in the `ORDER BY` statement, then `RAND()` will be calculated for all matching rows regardless of any `LIMIT`.

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15);
SELECT i, RAND(0) FROM t ORDER BY RAND(0) LIMIT 0, 1; # 0, 0.15522042769493574
SELECT i, RAND(0) FROM t ORDER BY RAND(0) LIMIT 1, 1; # 6, 0.2964166321758336
```