# Parallelization in MySQL, and problems with `RAND()`

Tags: mysql, sql, parallel-processing

**Underlying issue:** I have a table `main` with nearly a million rows. I wish to perform some operation for every row in `main`, and store the result in a `results` table.

Due to the size of the tables involved pretty much any query referencing both tables is quite slow.

Due to the amount of processing involved, I need multiple clients processing data in parallel.

---

**What I've done:** So, to speed things I have a `todo` table, with the same structure as `main`. Each client process randomly selects a row from `todo`, does work that takes ~30 seconds, and then removes the row from `todo`.

The query to randomly select is:

```sql
SELECT todo.id, todo.tag
FROM todo JOIN
    (SELECT
        (SELECT MIN(id) FROM todo) + (RAND() *
           (SELECT MAX(id) - MIN(id) FROM todo)
        ) AS val   --All this to get a random number between min and max
    ) AS r2
WHERE todo.id >= r2.val
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

See, e.g., [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast) and http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/.

---

**The problem with what I've done:** I'm getting a lot of "collisions" (that is, multiple entries of results for the same row in `main`. In other words, multiple clients processing the same information nearly simultaneously. This is okay, in that the db can support it (many results for each main), and I can do cleanup later, but not okay in that I'm consuming processing time unnecessarily.

When I say "a lot", I mean on the order of 10% to 15% of new entries duplicate.

I largely suspect this is due to problems with MySQL's `RAND()` function, as it has a history of problems and supposedly corrected bugs. (e.g., [MySQL RAND() seed values almost repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187207/mysql-rand-seed-values-almost-repeat))

However, due to the random selection, it's inevitable that there are gaps in the `todo` ids, and such gaps are only going to get larger ... thus the use of `>=` (which is necessary to return a result when the randomly generated id is in a gap), means that as gaps grow, collisions are increasingly likely.

*So, ... how can I parallelize this process while minimizing collisions (and doing very little extra work)? (Preferably using primarily SQL, without having to add intervening layers, such as a queue service.)*

Comment: Have you tried using a `MOD` capability? for example, having 4 parallel processes using `WHERE id MOD 4 = 0`, `WHERE id MOD 4 = 1`, etc.? it is fixed number of processes, but u can do as many as ud like without collision.

Comment: @PlantThelda The number of client processes running varies, so `MOD` isn't an easy answer.

Comment: Alright then, next question ... why does the row selection need to be random? Can you not establish a queue and process as FIFO?

Comment: As explained above, I'd like to avoid, if possible, writing a queue service layer. (Yes, it's pretty trivial to do, but still consumes network resources and has consequent latency of each check.) Random was a half-measure, but as I'm finding, perhaps not the best one.

Comment: Pick your poison my friend.